# Reconnect bar remains on screen after using wireless display

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, projector, miracast

Every time I disconnect my laptop from a wireless projector, a "Reconnect" bar appears on top of my screen:

[image]

It seems to be pinned and won't go away on its own, and the unpin button is grayed out so I can't hide it.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: If you right-click on the taskbar, do you see it under "Toolbars"? If you do, what is its exact name and can it be unchecked by a click?

Comment: @harrymc No, it doesn't appear in the Toolbars list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the new "Wireless Projection Banner" introduced in Windows 10
version 1809.

Two methods that you could try, both involving starting the Task Manager and then:

- End the process "Windows Shell Experience Host", or
- Right-click Explorer and select "Restart".